# web3 not working as expected in Parity

Tags: web3js, parity

I have a recurring problem with web3.  I follow the instructions on this page: https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Basic-Usage

Where it says "Node.js CLI Console" and instead of getting the expected results, this is the end of what I see:

```
     { [Function: send]
        method: [Object],
        request: [Function: bound ],
        call: 'shh_getSymKey' },
     deleteSymKey: 
      { [Function: send]
        method: [Object],
        request: [Function: bound ],
        call: 'shh_deleteSymKey' },
     newMessageFilter: 
      { [Function: send]
        method: [Object],
        request: [Function: bound ],
        call: 'shh_newMessageFilter' },
     getFilterMessages: 
      { [Function: send]
        method: [Object],
        request: [Function: bound ],
        call: 'shh_getFilterMessages' },
     deleteMessageFilter: 
      { [Function: send]
        method: [Object],
        request: [Function: bound ],
        call: 'shh_deleteMessageFilter' },
     post: 
      { [Function: send]
        method: [Object],
        request: [Function: bound ],
        call: 'shh_post' } },
  bzz: 
   Bzz {
     givenProvider: null,
     currentProvider: null,
     isAvailable: [Function],
     upload: [Function],
     download: [Function] } }
> web3.eth.blockNumber
undefined
>
```

Does anyone recognize this and if so what could I be missing?  I have tried installing web3 globally as root too but the result is the same.

Comment: I think the problem is with the version of web3. Try `npm install web3@0.20` to force the stable version, instead of the v1.0 beta that is installed by default.

Comment: Yes that worked!  If you make this an answer I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the version of web3 installed by default is v1.0 beta is not compatible with the wiki pages.

Try `npm install web3@0.20` to force the installation of the stable version.